# Unable to connect Jconsole to remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, jconsole

I have put the following text in setenv.sh

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
```

but still I am not able to connect JConsole to the remote server. What really should be the hostname there? I have checked the server.xml, it doesn't contain any ip in connector tag.

Or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706256/754167) worked for me. I was unable to connect Jconsole to remote tomcat server only because of that additional port requirement.