# JMX different port forward from kubernetes pod

Tags: java, kubernetes, profiling, jmx

I've got problem forwarding jmx from kubernetes pod to localhost.
Everything works fine when port is forwarded to the same port:

```
kubectl port-forward ... 9010:9010 OR
kubectl port-forward ... 9010
```

However, when I try to forward to a different local port,

```
kubectl port-forward ... 9011:9010
```

neither jconsole or jms can connect.

It is blocking me from profiling multiple applications at once.

JMS Error:

```
com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.ConnectionException caused by java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connect(RJMXConnection.java:406)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.ServerHandle.doConnect(ServerHandle.java:88)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.ServerHandle.connect(ServerHandle.java:78)
    at com.oracle.jmc.console.ui.editor.internal.ConsoleEditor$ConnectJob.run(ConsoleEditor.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2105)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:321)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connectJmxConnector(RJMXConnection.java:451)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.establishConnection(RJMXConnection.java:427)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connect(RJMXConnection.java:399)
    ... 4 more
```

jconsole error:

```
Connection to localhost:9011 did no succeed.
```

Comment: when you do the forwarding with different port , is there any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an RMI issue. The problem is that the RMI stub delivered to the JMX client is created for 9010 and so it fails when attempting to connect at 9011. There's a couple of decent solutions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093376/jconsole-over-ssh-local-port-forwarding). Another option is to switch to [JMXMP](https://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/jmx-rmi-vs-jmxmp/) which is a pure socket JMX protocol so port forwarding works without any additional workarounds.